# Give access to YouTube video Link after purchasing product

Tags: spring-boot, youtube-api

Below is an explanation of the problem, would be great if someone could explain me workflow and any possible API to use for it.

I am writing online education app for my Course project at Uni on SpringBoot + ReactJS. User can purchase course and each course has many videos. All videos are hosted on YouTube with private access. The moment User purchases the course, I want to give access to user's email automatically and then user can watch it.

Is there any other way to keep videos private so only those who purchased can watch them (I don't have time to write video player)?

Comment: Maybe there is a youtube API you can use to grant access and run it on a cron or something. If you need some special access control I'd make the time

Comment: As far as I know there is no such official API, as [this Git issue](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/174) summarizes similar Stack Overflow questions.